# Drupal 7 aggregator module with BBC persian feed

Tags: feeds

I am trying to import the BBC persian feed from http://www.bbc.co.uk/persian/index.xml using the Aggregator module in Drupal 7. For some reason, I always get the same link for the article for all the imported items. I have tried with other RSS feeds form BBC.co.uk; only the Persian  one is not properly imported.

Is this a know issue? Is there a workaround? I presume it is a problem with the RSS parser in the module, and the Persian numerals, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you add new feed, make sure you update the items twice after removing them in the first time.

steps as follow:

- add new feed
- go to feed aggregator page `admin/config/services/aggregator`
- update items manually by clicking on `update items` for the added feed
- remove items by clicking on `remove items` for the updated feed
- then update feed again `update items`

these steps worked for me while importing BBC persian and arabic feeds